# React native custom drawer opening button creation

Tags: react-native, react-native-drawer

I am currently learing react native. I want to use custom button for open drawer. Tried many codes and not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `navigation.openDrawer()` and `navigation.closeDrawer()` as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#setSoftInputMode(int))